# Getting data from Mysql Table in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to do this.  I'v created a custom field called `cp_country`.  Now each record in Mysql has a value for `cp_country`.  The problem is i don't understand how Wordpress indexes data into MySql.

For example look here

[image]

Normally, i'd be used to fetching rows like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE cp_country='United Kingdom'`
But as you can see the results aren't one row, the attributes are listed by per row joined by a post id.

How do i get a results `WHERE cp_country='United Kingdom'`?

For example  a set of results would each have `cp_country,cp_street,cp_price`.

Comment: Are you wanting to use this info in a post?

Comment: No not in a post.  This will be in a child theme.  i want to retrieve all posts WHERE `cp_country=United Kingdom`

Comment: Is my answer missing something? Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a WordPress Query...assuming you want to to be used in the front-end. For example, to query for all posts with `'cp_country' == 'United Kingdom'`:

```
<?php
// Query Args
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'cp_country',
    'meta_value' => 'United Kingdom'
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Do things with the post data
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You can alternatively use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), using a similar process. `get_posts()` will return an array of posts based on a set of parameters.